# interpolation of array inside a array

Tags: arrays, perl

When I was trying to print a specific element in array, I have mistakenly typed the name of the same array inside [ ] as element and got some output as shown. I thought that it is taking the size of the array and printing that number of characters, which was proven to be wrong by the output.

```
@array = (0..10, 12);

print "@array[@array]";
```

prints

```
 Use of uninitialized value in join or string at
 /home/VAR121/Program/Practise_Perl/Arrays.pl line 9.
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

I went one step ahead and edited code as shown below

```
print "@array[@array[@array]]";

output as: `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 0`  Use of uninitialized value in join or string at
 /home/VAR121/Program/Practise_Perl/Arrays.pl line 9.
```

Now I tried to put a number inside the second array instead of again giving array name as below.

```
print "@array[@array[1,2,3]]";
```

output as

```
 1 2 3
```

But no warning message this time.

What it is trying to print? and What is the reason behind this behavior.

Answer (score 9):

You're creating an array slice.  Start out by understanding that your array contains elements 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12.

That's a total of 12 elements (there is no value 11, but at index 11 you are storing the value 12).

Now when you use this construct: `@array[@array]` you're taking a slice, and requesting the values stored in indices 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, and 12.  There is no element with an index of 12 in your array.  The eleventh element has the value "12".

Answer (score 4):

`@array[]` is array slice notation.  For example:

`my @array = (qw/apple banana cucumber date/)`

`@array[1,2]` will return a list of (banana, cucumber) (index 1 and index 2 of @array).

Now, `@array[@array]` tries to take the values of the inner @array and use them as indexes of the outer @array. In your example, @array[@array] is equivalent to @array[0..10, 12]. Since one of the values of the inner array is 12, and the outer array has no index of 12, you get an undefined value warning.

Comment: `@array` is evaluated in list context within the square brackets that index the outer array, so the value is a list of all the values stored in `@array`, which are in turn used as indices.  So it's not quite right that the value of the inner array is 12.

Comment: @DavidO I said "a" value, as in one of them, not "the" value. I will change it to "one of the values".